# Kannel only sending 153 characters

Tags: sms, concatenation, sms-gateway, kannel

doing a bit of a project at the moment involving Kannel however I am having an issue.

When I send a long sms to the kannel gateway, it receives the first part of the sms and then uses the get-url to send my php script to add to the website. Then the second part gets sent and the same things happens.

Is there a way to send the full sms to the website?

Thanks very much in advance for any help. Below is my appended kannel.conf

```
group = core
admin-port = <snip>
admin-password = <snip>
status-password = <snip>
smsbox-port = <snip>
wdp-interface-name = "*"
log-file = "/var/log/kannel/bearerbox.log"
log-level = 0

group = smsc
smsc = at
modemtype = auto
device = /dev/ttyUSB1
speed = 9600
connect-allow-ip = 127.0.0.1

group = smsbox
bearerbox-host = 127.0.0.1
sendsms-port = <snip>
sendsms-chars = "0123456789 +-"
log-file = "/var/log/kannel/smsbox.log"
log-level = 0
access-log = "/var/log/kannel/access.log"
global-sender = <snip>
sms-length = 500

group = sendsms-user
username = <snip>
password = <snip>
concatenation = true

group = modems
id = huawei_e220
name = "Huawei_E220"
detect-string = "huawei"
message-storage = sm
speed = 9600

group = sms-service
keyword =
catch-all = 1
max-messages = 0
# trying this below
#assume-plain-text = true
concatenation = true
get-url =  "http://<snip>.net/inbound.php?phone=%p&text=%t"

# Ends
```

Answer (score 0):

It may have something to do with your GSM modem. If I try a very similar configuration with a real SMSC, the message is properly reassembled. Also, the `get-url` for your `sms-service` group is incorrect  - `%t` is message timestamp, if you want the whole message content, you should use `%a`. (At least that's the case with Kannel 1.5.0.)

Comment: Thank you very much pilsetnieks for your reply. I will do some more research into that.

Regarding the exit code, I apologise I was testing/playing with the exit codes and had the timestamp set at that time - it is now back to %a.

Comment: It may well be that your Kannel configuration is fine but the modem is not configured correctly and is doing something to the UDH in the messages so Kannel doesn't know those should be reassembled.

Comment: Got it working eventually after a lot of coffee and re-reading of the manual...will answer below however, thanks pilsetnieks for helping with this thread!

Answer (score 0):

So, the issue itself was to do with the routing of the messages from the bearerbox to the smsc and smsbox. Basically I had to define an smsc which pointed to the smsbox and that seemed to fix it. I do not have the code with me at the moment to post up however, for anyone else having this issue - please check your smsc settings.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following settings to **core** group to combine MO SM from parts:

```
group = core
...
sms-combine-concatenated-mo = 1
sms-combine-concatenated-mo-timeout = 600
```

If this will not help - add logging to your **smsc** section with debug level (log-level = 0) to see diagnostics from Kannel.